# How to create subtitle using sphinx

Tags: java, cmusphinx, subtitle, sphinx4

TranscriberDemo.java only gives word start and end timings , I need to get the hypothesis(the complete sentence. ) start and end timings is there any way to get that ??.

Comment: Please post text copy instead of linking an image. Try also to put some effort into text formatting, certainly not the worst but still hard to read without any paragraph and close to no punctuation.

Comment: Do you know the answer now.